# How to get all the distinct of columns in different category of another column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this. In 1 'noso' there are different 'code' with 'co' column with different 'state' and 'nodo'

| noso | nodo | code | co | do | state | line id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #S2233 | PR1 | A | 10 | 10 | done | 1 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | B | 15 | 15 | done | 2 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | C | 15 | 15 | done | 3 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | D | 15 | 15 | done | 4 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | E | 5 | 5 | done | 5 |
| #S2233 | PR2 | E | 5 | 0 | cancel | 6 |
| #S2233 | PR2 | F | 4 | 0 | cancel | 7 |
| #S2233 | PR3 | E | 5 | 0 | cancel | 8 |
| #S2233 | PR3 | F | 4 | 0 | cancel | 9 |
| #S2233 | PR3 | G | 7 | 0 | cancel | 10 |
| #S2233 | PR4 | E | 5 | 0 | cancel | 11 |
| #S2233 | PR4 | F | 4 | 0 | cancel | 12 |
| #S2233 | PR4 | G | 7 | 0 | cancel | 13 |

how I can get result like this with postgresql.

| noso | nodo | code | co | do | state | line id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #S2233 | PR1 | A | 10 | 10 | done | 1 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | B | 15 | 15 | done | 2 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | C | 15 | 15 | done | 3 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | D | 15 | 15 | done | 4 |
| #S2233 | PR1 | E | 5 | 5 | done | 5 |
| #S2233 | PR2 | F | 4 | 0 | cancel | 7 |
| #S2233 | PR3 | G | 7 | 0 | cancel | 10 |

I want to get distinct of every 'code' and 'co' in 'noso' column. but I want the all of the distinct (code,co) in **done** state **first** but if there are different codes from the done state (because I want all of the distinct code in 'noso' column) which is cancel state, I want all the distinct of code,co,do column too from the cancel state.

note:

- done state cant have duplicated code but cancel state is possible
- 'nodo' column of cancel state is not a problem what 'nodo' can be the result but must be from cancel state rows

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() to order, and partition your data:

Schema similar to yours:

```
create table mytable(noso varchar(10) ,nodo varchar(10),
               code varchar(10), 
               co varchar(10),
               dot varchar(10),
               state varchar(10),
               id int);
            
 insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR1','A','10','10','done',1);
 insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR1','B','15','15','done',2);
 insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR1','B','15','15','done',3);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2234','PR1','B','15','15','done',4);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR1','E','5','5','done',5);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR2','E','5','0','cancel',6);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR2','F','4','0','cancel',7);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR3','E','5','0','cancel',8);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR3','F','4','0','cancel',9);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR3','G','7','0','cancel',10);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR4','E','5','0','cancel',11);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR4','F','4','0','cancel',12);
insert into mytable 
(noso,nodo,code,co,dot,state,id)
values
('#S2233','PR4','G','7','0','cancel',13);
```

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by noso,code,co order by noso) as rownum
  FROM mytable
  where state != 'cancel') t
 WHERE rownum = 1
 UNION
 SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by noso,code,co,dot order by noso) as rownum
  FROM mytable t1
  where state = 'cancel' 
  and NOT EXISTS(
    select 1 FROM mytable where code = t1.code and state = 'done')
  ) t3
  WHERE rownum = 1
  order by state desc
```